# Razor pages with existing and api with own authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I am working an asp.net core 3.0 razor pages project, and I have added an api folder into it and it is all working.

But I want authentication on the api functions.

I already am using authentication/identity in my razor pages web site, and I have read about JWT which I "think" might be the way to go but is it possible to mix the existing identity/authentication with JWT used for the API only somehow?

So my api used at present the standard out of the box Visual Studio API:-

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PortfoliosController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly actools19bContext _context;

    public PortfoliosController(actools19bContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

etc...

And I have read about adding [Authorize] above the [Route("api/[controller]")] using as I say JWT but worried it will stop the standard razor pages website from working.

I have tried looking on Google in various places but can't find anyone that has done what I need to do (which perhaps is an indication mixing API with the razor website shouldn't be done?)

And my standard razor pages authentication is added using

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
                  policy.RequireRole("Admin", "Administrator"));
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("UserOnly", policy =>
                  policy.RequireRole("User"));
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
            });
```

etc.

Anybody done this kind of thing before or should I really be looking at the API as a seperate thing away from the razor website?

C

Answer (score 2):

You could set specific schemes on controllers to use specific auth , for your web api using JWT auth only, you could try

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyApiController : Controller
```

JWT is configured like below in startup(refer to [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/))

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)  
.AddJwtBearer(options =>  
{  
    //your options
});
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x